# python extract specific part of the changing string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have this URL string:

```
Hdf5File= '/home/Windows-Share/SCS931000126/20170101.h5'
```

I want to get two desired output from this string:

```
1- 'SCS931000126' 
2- '20170101'
```

I wrote this regular expression to extract the above mentioned outputs, so I wrote:

```
import re
print(re.split(r'/', (re.split(r'[a-f]',Hdf5File)[4]))[1])
print(re.split(r'\.', (re.split(r'/', (re.split(r'[a-f]',Hdf5File)[4]))[2]))[0])
```

This gives me the desired output(if there is a better way to extract these outputs please let me know).

But the case is that this part of the URL `/home/Windows-Share/` might change, is there anyway that I only get my desired output which are always at the end of the string regardless of the part of URL that might change?

for example if I have :

```
Hdf5File='/home/dal/windows-Share/SCS931000126/20170101.h5'
```

Then i cant re-use my regex. is there any way to this in a more reusable way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need `re.split`? You can just as well use `str.split` for this one:

```
In [294]: x, y = Hdf5File.split('/')[-2:]

In [296]: x, y.split('.')[0]
Out[296]: ('SCS931000126', '20170101')
```

Answer (score 2):

While a simple split will work as cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ already demonstrated, you can also use `os.path` to get parts of your url:

```
import os

Hdf5File= '/home/Windows-Share/SCS931000126/20170101.h5'

f = os.path.basename(Hdf5File)
d = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(Hdf5File))
print( d, f ) # SCS931000126 20170101.h5
# and to remove the file extension:
f = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
print(f) # 20170101
```